# Colision detecting in java(Tiled map)

Tags: java, dictionary, collision-detection, tile

Here i have a code with a picture moving around the map.

How to make this picture colide when interacte with map tiles ? I'm a beginer at java so i have no ideas. Any Help or advise is very welcome.

Code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import org.omg.CORBA.portable.InputStream;

import java.io.Reader;

public class NewTest extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Image TestImage;
private BufferedImage bf;
private BufferedImage bufferedImage;
private int cordX = 100;
private int cordY = 100;
public int mapy=25;
public int mapx=mapy;
 public int size= 20;
private boolean down, up, left, right;
private Image wall = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("image/Koala.jpg");
private Image no = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("image/house.jpg");

public static int[][] 
        map =               {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                             {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                            {0, 10, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 11},
                            {0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
                            {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
                            {0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
                            {0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
                            {0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
                            {0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
                            {0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
                            {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
                            {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
                            {0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
                            {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
                            {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
                            {0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
                            {0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
                            {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
                            {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
                            {0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
                            {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
                            {0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
                            {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
                            {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
                            {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
                            {0, 12, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 13}};

public NewTest() throws IOException {
    setTitle("Testing....");
    setSize(mapy*size+50,mapx*size+50);
    imageLoader();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void imageLoader() throws IOException {
    TestImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("image/Koala.jpg");

    addKeyListener(this);
}

public void update(Graphics g){
       paint(g);
}


public void paint(Graphics g){

    bf = new BufferedImage( this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

try{
animation(bf.getGraphics());
g.drawImage(bf,0,0,null);
}catch(Exception ex){

}


}

public void animation(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    for (int y = 0; y <= mapy; y++){
        for (int x = 0; x <= mapx; x++){

            int L = x * size;
            int U = y * size;
            int R = size;
            int D = size;
               /// g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(-90));

            if (map[y][x] == 1){
                //no black wall
                g2d.setColor(Color.green);
                g2d.fillRect(L, U, R, D);


            }else if (map[y][x] == 2){
                //on left
                g2d.setColor(Color.green);
                g2d.fillRect(L, U, R, D);
                g2d.setColor(Color.black);
                g2d.fillRect(L-size/2 +2, U, 8, size);

            }else if (map[y][x] == 3){
                //on right
                g2d.setColor(Color.green);
                g2d.fillRect(L, U, R, D);
                g2d.setColor(Color.black);
                g2d.fillRect(L+size, U, 8, size);

            }else if (map[y][x] == 4){
                //on top
                g2d.setColor(Color.green);
                g2d.fillRect(L, U, R, D);
                g2d.setColor(Color.black);
                g2d.fillRect(L, U-size/2 + 2, size, 8);

            }else if (map[y][x] == 5){
                //on bottom
                g2d.setColor(Color.green);
                g2d.fillRect(L, U, R, D);
                g2d.setColor(Color.black);
                g2d.fillRect(L, U+size, size, 8);
            }else if (map[y][x] == 10){
                //on bottom
                g2d.setColor(Color.green);
                g2d.fillRect(L, U, R, D);
                g2d.setColor(Color.black);
                g2d.fillRect(L, U-size/2 + 2, size, 8);
                g2d.fillRect(L-size/2 +2, U, 8, size );
            }else if (map[y][x] == 11){
                //on bottom
                g2d.setColor(Color.green);
                g2d.fillRect(L, U, R, D);
                g2d.setColor(Color.black);
                g2d.fillRect(L, U+size, size, 8);
            }else if (map[y][x] == 12){
                //on bottom
                g2d.setColor(Color.green);
                g2d.fillRect(L, U, R, D);
                g2d.setColor(Color.black);
                g2d.fillRect(L, U+size, size, 8);
            }else if (map[y][x] == 13){
                //on bottom
                g2d.setColor(Color.green);
                g2d.fillRect(L, U, R, D);
                g2d.setColor(Color.black);
                g2d.fillRect(L, U+size, size, 8);
            }

        }

    }
    g.drawImage(TestImage, cordX, cordY,20 , 20, this);

   }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        new NewTest();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
    switch (ke.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            right = true;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            left = true;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            down = true;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            up = true;
            break;
    }
    updateState();
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
    switch (ke.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            right = false;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            left = false;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            down = false;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            up = false;
            break;
    }
    updateState();
}

protected void updateState() {
    if (right) {
        cordX += 5;
    } else if (left) {
        cordX -= 5;

    }
    if (down) {
        cordY += 5;
    } else if (up) {
        cordY -= 3;
    }
    if (down && up) {
        cordY += 0;
        cordX += 0;
    }
    if (right && left) {
        cordX += 0;
        cordY += 0;
    }

    System.out.printf("X:");System.out.println(cordX);
    System.out.printf("Y:");System.out.println(cordY);
    repaint();
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
}

}
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good approach is to seperate visual and reality model. It means deep in the program, you have your "physics rules" and all objects and based on that model, you draw it.

You can start with creating class like this

```
public class ObjectInMyGame{
  private int posx;
  private int posy;
  private int width;
  private int height;
  private Image image;
  private int movingX;
  private int movingY;
  //Note that it is good to use Point or something like that, instead of posx, posy.
}
```

Then it is good to have some kind of "game controller", which is running your whole world.

```
public class GameController{
  List<ObjectInMyGame> objects;

  public updateGame(){
    for (ObjectInMyGame object : objects){
      object.doSomething(); //sometimes it is good idea to let objects itself do something
    }
  }
}
```

So for example, when you move object, you can check, if he collide or not and then decide what to do.